# How to Update by using dropdownlist value

Tags: asp.net

work on asp.net vs05.I have two table

```
Table A        Table B
   ID          DistrictID
   Name        DistrictName
   FName
   MName
   District
```

By using the table a i fill a gridview

```
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView4" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SQL" DataKeyNames="StudentID" EmptyDataText="No information to display">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentID" HeaderText="StudentID" SortExpression="StudentID" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentName" HeaderText="StudentName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FatherName" HeaderText="FatherName" SortExpression="FatherName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DivisionName" HeaderText="DivisionName" />
                    <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQL" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:JobTestConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT StudentID, StudentName, FatherName FROM studentInfo" UpdateCommand="UPDATE studentInfo SET StudentID = @StudentID, StudentName = @StudentName, FatherName = @FatherName WHERE (StudentID = @StudentID)">
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="StudentID" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="StudentName" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="FatherName" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now i  set a DropDownList on this grid .I set this on templetField.I want to fill this ddl by Table-B and also want  edit command  work correctly.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView4" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SQL" EmptyDataText="No information to display">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentID" HeaderText="StudentID" SortExpression="StudentID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentName" HeaderText="StudentName" SortExpression="StudentName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FatherName" HeaderText="FatherName" SortExpression="FatherName" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DivisionName" SortExpression="DivisionName">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlD" DataTextField="StudentName"
                            DataValueField="StudentName" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("DivisionName", "{0}") %>'>
                        </asp:DropDownList><asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlD" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:JobTestConnectionString %>"
                            SelectCommand="SELECT [StudentName] FROM [Division]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DivisionName") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Run this snipt browser show the bellow error:

**'DropDownList2' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value**

**Now my question is how to set ddl by Table-B.After fill i want to update Table-A by using the command field of gridview.**

plz correct tag if necessary

Answer (score 2):

Well your drop down list is being filled with StudentNames, yet you're binding the selected value to a DivisionName.